# Unable to fit OpenGL ES view to screen with iOS 8/9 SDK

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, ios8, orientation, ios9

I have a universal landscape app built from Apple's old OpenGLES example, and when I build in XCode 6 or 7 the view is sideways:

[image: sideways]

Apple has broken my rotation before, and previous times I fixed it just by using transforms to rotate and scale my view, which worked fine.

With XCode 6/7, if I rotate the layer using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation() then the rotation is correct but it retains the original aspect ratio:

[image]

That should be easy to fix with scaling, but I weirdly cannot scale it to fit the screen.  I can match the width or height:

[image: matched width]

[image: matched height]

But no matter what values I use for height/width scaling, it's not possible to scale both height and width to the screen.  This is what I get when I set (what should be) the correct scaling values:

[image]

I've experimented a bunch with the scaling, and for some reason the width and height do not appear to be fully independent of each other.  Autolayout is off and I can't find anywhere that constraints are set.  I've also tried settings the view bounds and frame, but it has exactly the same weird scaling limitations that I get when I use a transform.

If I rotate the pixel dimensions of the OpenGL buffer, then it appears at the correct size, but the right side is cut off.  I never could find any way to fix this either:

[image]

The only thing that makes the view fit correctly is changing the app's plist orientations from Landscape Left/Right to standard Portrait only.  But this creates orientation problems when interacting with other music apps since my software is not actually operating in portrait -- the orientation sometimes flips when switching apps, and half the time my app starts upside down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being that the view containing the OpenGL layer was actually not being framed properly.  I'd investigated this possibility before and thought the framing was correct, and I'm still not sure why my app worked before or how it got into this state where the frame wasn't set correctly.  But the solution that worked for me was to match the OpenGL view's frame and bounds to its superview in its layoutSubviews() callback.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews // for UIView containing OpenGL layer
{
    [self remakeFramebuffer];

    self.bounds = self.superview.bounds;
    self.frame = self.superview.frame;
    self.center = self.superview.center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scaling the view is not appropriate in the first place, you should avoid that. You gave a bit too little information on how are you doing what you are doing but I can imagine you used a custom setup with creating your own frame buffer as it was in the old example...

In this case you must understand this is more or less iOS unique procedure which is similar to creating a FBO. In most platforms the frame buffer will resize with your view but not in yours. The easiest fix in your situation would simply be recreating the buffers. On rotation change delete the frame and the render buffer, then recreate them.

Probably a better solution would be to create a square view large enough to fill the screen and position it in the center. Your view should then be correctly placed and rotated always but you will manually need to set the viewport:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        CGFloat size = frame.size.width>frame.size.height?frame.size.width:frame.size.height;
        self.glView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(.0f, .0f, size, size)];
        self.glView.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*.5f, self.frame.size.height*.5f);
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    // the view should already have corect size
    [self resetViewport];
}
- (void)resetViewport {
    CGFloat scale = 1.0f; // A scale you use on the layer (if any) when creating the render buffer. These are usually depending on the display (2x, 3x)
    CGFloat xOffset = (self.glView.frame.size.width-self.frame.size.width)*.5f;
    CGFloat yOffset = (self.glView.frame.size.height-self.frame.size.height)*.5f;
    glViewport(xOffset*scale, yOffset*scale, self.frame.size.width*scale, self.frame.size.height*scale);
}
```

Something like this should do. Also remember to reset the viewport after the buffer initialization. Also you may consider animating the viewport values to get a nice animation when the device changes orientation.

Comment: My app was already set up like you describe, but the info in your comment lead me to discovering that the view's frame and bounds was actually not being set correctly.

Comment: Good job on finding out that one. Still I kind of don't like recreating the buffer. Maybe at some point you should consider the other approach with having a square view and simply playing with viewport. As I said, it might be very easy to animate it as well and it does exactly what you need.

Comment: Isn't the larger square view only useful if your app supports both portrait and landscape orientation?  Mine is landscape only.  I can actually remove the 'remakeFramebuffer' call from layoutSubviews and it still works and rotates fine.  The way I have it set up, the rotation is already animated for me by viewcontroller when orientation changes.  I used to flip it myself but I now let the system do it.

Comment: Well if you only have landscape orientation you should have no issues at all. You may use the same buffer without any scaling or any other transforming. I guess your problem was only in setting the frame of the view...